# Dynamic graphing using Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Right now I'm using JFreeChart in order to create a dynamic chart. However the chart is significantly slowing down my GUI. I was just wondering, is jfreechart generally heavy in the graphics department (my computer is not fast at all). Or is there a way to configure the ChartPanel to better optimize dynamic charting.

Comment: Good question. I did this for a project once, and I know that it actually worked with reasonable speed, but I don't remember what configuration or modification we had to do to reach that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JFreechart library by itself does not cause the UI to be much slower. But definitely being on slow PC created problem in UI rendering as browser has to do much more pixel drawing with charts.
Still you can look at the following link and see if the tricks described can help you

http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=12682

Comment: Well I turned off anti aliasing and the drawing of the chart became faster however the GUI still remains slow

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding data to the JFreeChart dataset at a high rate?  Have you considered shutting off notifications when you add a batch of data, then re-enabling?

```
 JFreeChart.setNotify(false)
```